# What is the return type of document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have the following list:

```
  <ol>
    <li>Cookies <ol>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li class="test1">Chocolate </li>
   </ol>
```

and I perform this selection at the end of my html

```
 var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('li:first-of-type');
```

When I tried in Chrome `nodes.forEach` it gave me an error. When I looked at the value it looked like an array. I actually was able to navigate it using a regular for like:

```
for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
   nodes[i].onclick= function(){ alert('Hello!'); };
}
```

So, what is the actual returned type of `document.querySelectorAll`? why array methods did not work?

So, it looks like an array, can workaround it to make it work like an array but it is not an array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

---

The type of the result is a NodeList.
Since it is an Array-like object, you can run the `map`, `forEach` and other Array.prototype functions on it like this:

```
var result = document.querySelectorAll('a');
Array.prototype.map.call(result, function(t){ return t; })
```

The `map`, `forEach`, `any` and other functions in the Array prototype work on Array-like objects. For example, let's define an object literal with numerical indexes (0,1) and a length property:

```
var arrayLike = { '0': 'a', '1': 'b', length: 2};
```

The forEach method, applied to the `arrayLike` object will like on a real Array.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arrayLike, function(x){ console.log(x) } ); //prints a and b
```

Comment: Using `call` and `apply`, you can pass the execution context as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks @GiovanniFilardo. What I am wondering now is why I can do it through Array.prototype.[method].call and yet the object itself is not an "array"

Comment: Looks like an array, can work around it to make it work like an array but it is not an array?

Comment: @Dalorzo I edited the answer to expand on the `call` and `apply` argument, because in the comment the code is not as readable.

Comment: Thank for the award :-)
I realized just now what you meant by asking "can work around it to make it work like an array". The answer is yes/no. You could put the `forEach` or `map` function of Array.prototype in the prototype of your result. For example: var result = document.querySelectorAll('a'); result.constructor.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
result.forEach(function(el){ console.log(el) });
This usually works almost exactly like you expect. I would not change the prototype of built-in objects, though.

Answer (score 6):

In the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll), it says that :

> [the returned list of elements] is a non-live `NodeList` of element objects.

[`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) is different from an array (entirely-different prototype-chain) and the documentation also tells you why you cannot use `forEach`:

> **Why can't I use `forEach` or `map` on a `NodeList`?**
>
> `NodeList` are used very much like arrays and it would be tempting to use `Array.prototype` methods on them, however they don't have those methods.
>
> JavaScript has an inheritance mechanism based on prototypes for both built–in objects (like `Array`s) and host objects (like `NodeList`s). `Array` instances inherit array methods (such as `forEach` or `map`) because their prototype chain looks like the following:
>
> `myArray --> Array.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null` (The prototype chain of an object can be obtained by calling Object.getPrototypeOf several times.)
>
> `forEach`, `map` and the likes are own properties of the `Array.prototype` object.
>
> Unlike arrays, `NodeList` prototype chain looks like the following:
>
> `myNodeList --> NodeList.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null`
>
> `NodeList.prototype` contains the item method, but none of the `Array.prototype` methods, so they cannot be used on `NodeLists`.

However, there are workarounds. Again from the documentation, you can use the `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.map` methods directly like so:

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
var firstDiv = divs[ 0 ];

forEach.call(firstDiv.childNodes, function( divChild ){
  divChild.parentNode.style.color = '#0F0';
});
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems `NodeLists` *can* now be accessed like an array* in this
[updated documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

> **Accessing the matches**
>
> Once the NodeList of matching elements is returned, you can examine it just like any array. If the array is empty (that is, its length property is 0), then no matches were found.
>
> Otherwise, you can simply use standard array notation to access the contents of the list. You can use any common looping statement, such as:

```
var highlightedItems = userList.querySelectorAll(".highlighted");

highlightedItems.forEach(function(userItem) {
  deleteUser(userItem);
});
```

*While you can now use `forEach`, other methods like `map` are not available.

Comment: The type is `NodeList`. I'm not sure what you mean by "anything" separated by commas; perhaps it looks like that on the console, but that is simply the string representation of the `NodeList`; the resemblance is superficial.

Comment: What I mean is what @Giovanni just posted I can use  Array.prototype.forEach.call. This gives me the impression the "nodes" returned are of type array, isn't?

Comment: No. The fact that you can use it with `Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't mean that the `NodeList` is an array. You can see that from the prototype chain. It just means that `NodeList` conforms to whatever interface that `forEach` requires to traverse through each element of a list.

Comment: `arguments` is also array-like.. this article was helpful: http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/