# .call behavior on iterating DOM node list

Tags: javascript

How does following code works?

```
var myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('li'); // grabs some <li>
[].forEach.call(myNodeList, function (item) {
  // :) hooray `item` can be used here
});
```

Whereas ,

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach.call(myNodeList, function (item) {
      // throws error
});
```

Read something - `This accesses the created (empty) array’s prototype method and using call allows the NodeList to take advantage.`

Any help would be appreciated.

### Question is

What makes following code access the created (empty) array’s prototype method and using call allows the NodeList to take advantage

```
[].forEach.call(myNodeList, function (item) {
  // :) hooray `item` can be used here
});
```

https://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('li')` return [array like result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714854/492258) to apply `foreach` you should use [Array.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22950264/492258)

```
Array.apply(null, document.querySelectorAll('li')).forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item)
  });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6f8wodx/)